# Error enabling MPM Worker

Tags: apache-2.2, php, mpm-worker

I am struggling to enable MPM Worker

I uncommented `#HTTPD=/usr/sbin/httpd.worker` in `/etc/sysconfig/httpd` and restarted Apache but I am receiving these error:

> Starting httpd: httpd.worker: Syntax error on line 222 of `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` Syntax error on line 9 of `/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf`: Cannot load `/etc/httpd/modules/libphp5-zts.so` into server: `/etc/httpd/modules/libphp5-zts.so`: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: do you have the file /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5-zts.so

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install `php-zts` package:

```
Name        : php-zts
Version     : 5.3.8
Release     : 2.el5.art
Architecture: x86_64
Size        : 4210728
Packager    : None
Group       : Development/Languages
URL         : http://www.php.net/
Repository  : atomic
Summary     : Thread-safe PHP interpreter for use with the Apache HTTP Server
Description :
The php-zts package contains a module for use with the Apache HTTP
Server which can operate under a threaded server processing model.
```

and make sure that this extension exists in `/etc/httpd/modules`:

```
ls -l /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5-zts.so 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4210728 Nov  1 05:29 /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5-zts.so
```